# Cannot see _ (underscore) in WPF content

Tags: wpf, xaml

A very simple question:

Why I cant see `_` (underscore) in WPF content?

For instance the content of

```
<Label Content="test_t" Name="label2"  />
```

is shown as `"testt"` (with the underscore not shown).

Comment: did you tried to escape it? `__` or `\_` (just guessing with 2nd suggestion)

Comment: HI , I wanted to know its reason,as one of my friend from stackoverflow said, its like the & in windows forms.Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Labels support mnemonics (i.e. you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>(key)</kbd> to give them focus). You define the mnemonic key using an underscore.

http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/01/061004.html

If you want to see underscores, replace single underscores with double underscores.

Answer (score 11):

This is because `Label` supports defining a mnemonic based on its content, which is done by prefixing the mnemonic with an underscore (the same thing that happens in Windows Forms with `&`).

Use a double underscore if you want a literal one to appear:

```
<Label Content="test__t" Name="label2"  />
```

Answer (score 7):

I know im late to the party but I believe that if you don't have the Label associated to a TextBox than you should use a TextBlock instead.

Changing your control to a TextBlock solves this issue since only Label has  the mnemonic support

Comment: We were showing "file no longer found" message in label where the user used _ as a part of the file name, and only the first _ was removed (not removed but underscored the first character after the _). This answer is the answer that will fix the situation like ours.

Answer (score 5):

This style solves your problem:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type Label}"
   TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                  RecognizesAccessKey="False"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                         Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: this one works perfectly instead of adding unnecessarily an extra '_'

Answer (score 4):

I was binding to a data source which I didn't want to change, so I used a custom converter to create the missing underscore:

```cs
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]
public class ShowUnderscoreConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        value is string text ? text.Replace("_", "__") : null;

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => 
        value is string text ? text.Replace("__", "_") : null;
}
```