# TreeView with Chekbox only on children

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have an XML document of this type.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Parameters>
  <Param Name="Father0_0" ID="1">
    <Param0 Name="Father0_1" ID="2">
      <Param1 Name="Father0_2" ID="3">
        <Param2 Name="Child0_0" ID_ch="1"/>
      </Param1>
      <Param1 Name="Father0_3" ID="4">
        <Param2 Name="Father0_4" ID="5">
          <Param3 Name="Child0_3" ID_ch="2"/>
        </Param2>
      </Param1>
    </Param0>
  </Param>
  <Param Name="Father1_0" ID="6">
    <Param0 Name="Child1_0" ID_ch="3" />
  </Param>
  <Param Name="Father2_0" ID="7">
    <Param1 Name="Child2_0" ID_ch="3"/>
  </Param>
 <Param Name="Child3_0" ID_ch="4"/>
</Parameters>
```

.CS

So I load my XML

```
XmlDataProvider _xml = FindResource("xmldata") as XmlDataProvider;
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load("34.xml");
_xml.Document = xmlDocument;
```

if I do so as described below in XAML I get Chechkboks the on all items in treeview?

.XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
 <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmldata" XPath="Parameters"/>
<!--The same is done for the Param0,Param1,Param2,Param3 changing DataType=""-->
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Param" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath= ./*}">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <CheckBox Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
   </StackPanel>
 </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<!-------------------------------->
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
 <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmldata}, XPath=Param}"  />
</Grid>
```

How to make a CheckBox only for children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generic approach for customizing `TreeView` in case of XML data is to make your own data template selector:

```
public class ItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ParentTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate ChildTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var element = item as XElement;
        if (element != null)
        {
            return element.Elements().Any() ? ParentTemplate : ChildTemplate;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

Here's how it can be used in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ItemTemplateSelector x:Key="ItemTemplateSelectorKey">

            <local:ItemTemplateSelector.ParentTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Attribute[Name].Value}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </local:ItemTemplateSelector.ParentTemplate>

            <local:ItemTemplateSelector.ChildTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Attribute[Name].Value}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:ItemTemplateSelector.ChildTemplate>

        </local:ItemTemplateSelector>
    </Window.Resources>

    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Root.Elements}"
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ItemTemplateSelectorKey}"/>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = XDocument.Parse(Properties.Resources.XmlFile);
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Note, that I've been used [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) API instead of `XmlDocument` one.

**UPD**
`ChildTemplate` is simplified a little to be more readable, but this has an issue with displaying underscore in content (e.g., see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7861722/580053) answer for explanation).

Comment: Works perfectly, underscore only example, tell me how when clicking on the checkbox to get information about the child and parent. i mean from xml tag "Name", "Value", "ID". Thank you very much.

Comment: XML isn't a good choice for your data context, when you need some complex logic. If you need a code like "when checkbox is clicked, then do something", then consider converting your XML to view models.

Comment: I corrected the XML above, when i click on the checkbox need to get the id of the child and the id of its first parent

Comment: Thank you very much for the help I have done so - I Add in :          <CheckBox Content="{Binding Attribute[Name].Value}"  Checked="Box1_Checked"/>                                                                      and get data so :                                                                                    CheckBox chkSelecttedItem = (CheckBox)sender;
var _dc = (XElement)chkSelecttedItem.DataContext;
var ID_par = _dc.Parent.Attribute("ID").Value;
var ID_ch = _dc.LastAttribute.Value;

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `TreeViewItem` has no item then that is the child node and you can bind your `CheckBox.Visibility` as:

```
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Param" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath= ./*}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="{Binding XPath=@Name}" >
                <CheckBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </CheckBox.Style>
            </CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Works but completely hides the name of the parent, you need to add a textbox in stackPanel, Thank you very much.